# Do ads decrease interest for a site?

Tags: advertising

Is it true that if a user sees an ad on my site, the probability that he will return to the site in the future, decreases?

Also: Would having ads on site decrease the probability that the site will get positive reviews in blogs, Google +1 and Facebook likes and other kudos and blessings?

Comment: Ask yourself: Would you likely return to an ad-bloated page or recommend it to friends?

Comment: @Marcel Who said anything about "bloated?"

Comment: What @Marcel said -- there's a certain balance between ads and content that you need to find by trial and error. Try looking at successful newspapers and magazines and see what kind of balance they achieve.

Comment: This question is closed, so it’s too late. However, I think there is some merit in researching into this. If by “interest” you mean the likelihood of users returning, it’s pretty obvious that the more you annoy the user, the less likely the user will come back.

Answer (score 2):

Depends entirely on how intrusive they are.  When ads are common on the net, few ads that don't harm the usability of your page may have no impact on returns at all.

Answer (score 2):

it totally depends how you show them in your page. if your page would be full of ads all over the page, obviously this will affect negatively in visitor's mind.

Look at Gmail or Facebook or any famous site, and find how they manage their ads in web page.

Sometimes ads are useful when they are relative to web page content. Give preference to your website content than ad.